# Checking convergence of an iteration

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods

> How to check if an algorithm converges in an interval, for example $x_{k+1}:=\frac{1}{11}(1-\cos(x_k))$ does it converge for any startpoint $x_0\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)\setminus\{0\}$ ? (as hint: consider the Taylor approximation)

I know only the fixed point theorem of Banach, here if i choose $g(x)=\frac{1}{11}(1-\cos(x))$, differentiable with $g'(x)<1$ but the domain is not a closed set, is this a big problem ?

What has Taylor series to do with this ?

Comment: "but the domain is not a closed set" If you take its closure, can you extend the map to that? Does the extension still have the needed properties?

Comment: No. On the one hand, the empty set does not belong to the codomain (which must be a subset of the domain, since we iterate), on the other, for Banach's fixed point theorem, you need a continuous function, so the extension must at least be continuous.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes i noticed,but because of the factor $1/11$ the extension is possible not ?

Comment: Look at $g$. If you for a moment ignore the problem statement, what would its natural domain be?

Comment: @DanielFischer whole $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: Right. So extending is no problem at all. Does the extension do what you need it to do? Is it a contraction?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Yes it is.

Comment: Then Banach says it's done. Without Banach's theorem, you could use the Taylor expansion of $g$ to deduce that $x_k \to 0$. What are the first few terms of the Taylor expansion?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer aha So i consider the first 3-4 terms of Taylor (Polynomial) if i differentiate then with the given domain the derivative is also strict smaller than 1.

Comment: I wouldn't differentiate that. You know that the range of $g$ is (contained in) $[0,\frac{2}{11}]$. Then standard estimates of the remainder suffice.

Answer (score 1):

is our solution is $x^*$ then we are hoping our iteration is a fixed point problem so $g(x^*)=x^*$, now if $g'(x)\lt 1$, then it has lipschitz constant $L\lt1$, so:

$\|x^*-x^{k+1}\|=\|g(x^*)-g(x^k)\|\leq L\|x^*-x^k\|\lt\|x^*-x^k\|$

So we see as  $k\to\infty$ $x^k\to x^*$, so the iteration converges.

Also your split and open domain does not make a difference, we have a contraction, so if $x^0\in(-\pi/2,0)$ then we will stay in that interval, likewise if $x^0\in(0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: I can't follow your argumentation, ''So we see the iteration converges''. How can you justify the Lipschitz continuity ?

Comment: use the mean value theorem so $\|g(x)-g(y)\|\leq\sup_z|g'(z)|\|x-y\|\lt 1\times\|x-y\|$,

I.e $g$ is lipschitz continuous with lipschitz constant $L\lt 1$, 

we apply this to get the result above, and we have:

$\|x^*-x^{k+1}\|\lt\|x^*-x^k\|$, i.e. as we iterate we get closer and closer to the solution, hence we have convergence.

Comment: Does it make sense?

Comment: Also the reason that $0$ is removed from the domain of initial conditions, is because if we let $x^0=0$ we will get stuck since $g(0)=0$.